# Flutter Hive retrieve box elements and obtain key when using ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

Using Hive, I can `Hive.openBox('boxName')` to then pass into a `ListView.builder` and cast the entry to a Model to get the required information for my view like this:

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: list?.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final location = list.getAt(index) as Location; //casting to a Model
        
        //Widget code here to use location.ModelProperty, etc.
    },
 )
```

This works great, but I really need to be able to get the box's entry `key` record. All of my records are being saved with a key like `await box.put(nowSinceEpoch.toString(), data)`. How would I refactor this to still be able to pass in the box itself, and not have to do additional mapping or manipulation of the data being passed into the `ListView.builder`?

Comment: Please do not use [hive] tag for questions not about Apache hive. Please create another tag. flutter-hive or dart-hive, etc.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind, is to save `nowSinceEpoch.toString()` in the Location object. This way you will always have entry `key` of the object.